FastAPI SQLAlchemy Cannot "determine join condition between parent/child relationships"
Ive been trying to produce a FastAPI API to access my MySQL database. I produced the following 'Models' for the database:
from.database import Base
from sqlalchemy import CHAR, CheckConstraint, Column, ForeignKeyConstraint, Index, String, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import TINYINT
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship 
from typing import Optional, List

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Keyset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'keyset'
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('(`revision` > 0)', name='keyset_setrevision_gt_zero'),
    )

    setname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    revision: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(TINYINT, primary_key=True)
    profile: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(15))

    vendor: Mapped[List['Vendor']] = relationship('Vendor', secondary='sold', back_populates='keyset', lazy='joined')
    kit: Mapped[List['Kit']] = relationship('Kit', secondary='belongsto', back_populates='keyset', lazy='joined')
    manufacturer: Mapped[List['Manufacturer']] = relationship('Manufacturer', secondary='produces', back_populates='keyset', lazy='joined')


class Kit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'kit'
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('(`kitrevision` > 0)', name='kit_revision_gt_zero'),
    )

    kitname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    kitsetname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    kitrevision: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(TINYINT, primary_key=True)
    kittype: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(5))
    supportdescription: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(300))

    keyset: Mapped[List['Keyset']] = relationship('Keyset', secondary='belongsto', back_populates='kit', lazy='joined')
    listing: Mapped[List['Listing']] = relationship('Listing', secondary='sells', back_populates='kit', lazy='joined')


class Listing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'listing'

    listingid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(7), primary_key=True)
    price: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(11))

    kit: Mapped[List['Kit']] = relationship('Kit', secondary='sells', back_populates='listing', lazy='joined')
    mechmarketpost: Mapped[List['Mechmarketpost']] = relationship('Mechmarketpost', secondary='lists', back_populates='listing', lazy='joined')


class Manufacturer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'manufacturer'

    manufacturerid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(7), primary_key=True)
    manufacturername: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(50))
    addressline: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100))
    country: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(100))
    zipcode: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(20))

    keyset: Mapped[List['Keyset']] = relationship('Keyset', secondary='produces', back_populates='manufacturer', lazy='joined')


class Mechmarketpost(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mechmarketpost'

    postid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(7), primary_key=True)
    url: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(500))

    listing: Mapped[List['Listing']] = relationship('Listing', secondary='lists', back_populates='mechmarketpost', lazy='joined')


class Vendor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'vendor'

    vendorid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(7), primary_key=True)
    vendorname: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(CHAR(100))
    url: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(String(500))

    keyset: Mapped[List['Keyset']] = relationship('Keyset', secondary='sold', foreign_keys='[Vendor.vendorid]', back_populates='vendor', lazy='joined')


t_belongsto = Table(
    'belongsto', Base.metadata,
    Column('kitname', String(50), ForeignKey('kit.kitname'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('kitsetname', String(50), ForeignKey('kit.kitsetname'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('kitrevision', TINYINT, ForeignKey('kit.kitrevision'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('setname', String(50), ForeignKey('keyset.setname'), nullable=False),
    Column('revision', TINYINT, ForeignKey('keyset.revision'), nullable=False),
    CheckConstraint('(`kitrevision` > 0)', name='belongto_kitrevision_gt_zero'),
    CheckConstraint('(`revision` > 0)', name='belongto_setrevision_gt_zero'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['kitname', 'kitsetname', 'kitrevision'], ['kit.kitname', 'kit.kitsetname', 'kit.kitrevision'], name='belongto_fk2'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['setname', 'revision'], ['keyset.setname', 'keyset.revision'], name='belongto_fk1'),
    Index('belongto_fk1', 'setname', 'revision')
)


t_lists = Table(
    'lists', Base.metadata,
    Column('listingid',String(7), ForeignKey('listing.listingid'), primary_key=True),
    Column('postid', String(7), ForeignKey('post.postid'), nullable=False),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['listingid'], ['listing.listingid'], name='lists_fk2'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['postid'], ['mechmarketpost.postid'], name='lists_fk1'),
    Index('lists_fk1', 'postid')
)


t_produces = Table(
    'produces', Base.metadata,
    Column('setname', String(50), ForeignKey('keyset.setname'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('revision', TINYINT, ForeignKey('keyset.revision'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('manufacturerid', String(7), ForeignKey('manufacturer.manufacturerid'), nullable=False),
    CheckConstraint('(`revision` > 0)', name='produces_revision_gt_zero'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['manufacturerid'], ['manufacturer.manufacturerid'], name='produces_fk1'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['setname', 'revision'], ['keyset.setname', 'keyset.revision'], name='produces_FK2'),
    Index('produces_fk1', 'manufacturerid')
)


t_sells = Table(
    'sells', Base.metadata,
    Column('listingid', String(7), ForeignKey('listing.listingid'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('kitname', String(50), ForeignKey('kit.kitname'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('kitsetname', String(50), ForeignKey('kit.kitsetname'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('kitrevision', TINYINT, ForeignKey('kit.kitrevision'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['kitname', 'kitsetname', 'kitrevision'], ['kit.kitname', 'kit.kitsetname', 'kit.kitrevision'], name='sells_fk2'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['listingid'], ['listing.listingid'], name='sells_fk1'),
    Index('sells_fk2', 'kitname', 'kitsetname', 'kitrevision')
)


t_sold = Table(
    'sold', Base.metadata,
    Column('setname', String(50), ForeignKey('keyset.setname'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('revision', TINYINT, ForeignKey('keyset.revision'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('vendorid', String(7), ForeignKey('vendor.vendorid'), nullable=False),
    CheckConstraint('(`revision` > 0)', name='sold_revision_gt_zero'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['setname', 'revision'], ['keyset.setname', 'keyset.revision'], name='sold_fk2'),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['vendorid'], ['vendor.vendorid'], name='sold_fk1'),
    Index('sold_fk1', 'vendorid')

)

These models run fine until an endpoint in FastAPI is accessed. The code for the endpoint is:
@app.get("/keysets", response_model=list[schemas.Keyset])
def read_keysets(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    keysets = crud.get_keysets(db)
    return keysets


with the get_keysets() code being:
def get_keysets(db: Session):
    return db.query(models.Keyset).all()

When the endpoint is accessed through the FastAPI docs i get the following terminal text:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to
initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.
Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[Keyset(keyset)]'. Original exception was:
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on
relationship Keyset.vendor - there are no foreign keys linking these
tables via secondary table 'sold'.  Ensure that referencing columns
are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify
'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.

This is saying that there is no foreign keys referencing the columns, but both the Keyset and Vendor model both have their columns referenced in the secondary table 'sold' such these keys should join both these tables and form the relationship. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my code?
Note: In the relationship() method I used foriegn_keys="[...]" for the relationships but this still stated there are no foreign keys linking these tables, such I removed it.

I get errors trying to create the tables (admittedly on MariaDb).  Can you provide a [mre], just the two models and the association table that reproduces the issue?
